# Unable to locate package when running apt-get

Tags: 12.04, apt, rvm

I installed rvm and it tells me I'm missing some packages:

```
viggy@viggy:~$ rvm requirements
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
Skipping `apt-get update` make sure your system is up to date.
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
Missing required packages: libreadline6-dev, zlib1g-dev, libssl-dev, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev, sqlite3, libxml2-dev, libxslt1-dev, autoconf, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, automake, libtool, bison, libffi-dev.
```

So I try to install them but get a ton of unable to locate package errors:

```
viggy@viggy:~$ sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install libreadline6-dev, zlib1g-dev, libssl-dev, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev, sqlite3, libxml2-dev, libxslt1-dev, autoconf, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, automake, libtool, bison, libffi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libreadline6-dev,
E: Unable to locate package zlib1g-dev,
E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev,
E: Unable to locate package libyaml-dev,
E: Unable to locate package libsqlite3-dev,
E: Unable to locate package sqlite3,
E: Unable to locate package libxml2-dev,
E: Unable to locate package libxslt1-dev,
E: Unable to locate package autoconf,
E: Unable to locate package libgdbm-dev,
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5-dev,
E: Unable to locate package automake,
E: Unable to locate package libtool,
E: Unable to locate package bison,
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a comma after all the package names. Remove the commas.

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your /etc/apt/sources.list file and to decide which software repository you will use to fetch those missing packages, and add those repository/ies.

The easiest and fastest way is with the GUI-programs 'Synaptic package manager' and 'Software & Updates'

More difficult is via the CLI. You can find it on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: And what if I was using ubuntu server, what would be the solution?

Comment: You mean headless? Without GUI? Same solution. Use the CLI.

Comment: I read the documentation you sent me. So your recommendation is to uncomment some of the repositories in /etc/apache/sources.list and run sudo apt-get update? But how do I know which of those repositories are the ones I need?

Comment: what ubuntu are you using? can you post the information from 'sudo uname -a' ?

Comment: Linux viggy 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:15:33 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: On http://packages.ubuntu.com/ you can check all missing packages. Normally they should all be available in the Precise release. So adding "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise restricted main" and "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring restricted universe main multiverse" to your /etc/apt/sources.list" should work. Then run "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get install (yourpackage)"